# How to use function - CAST(datetime as date) of SQL Server in sqlalchemy?

Tags: python, sql-server, sqlalchemy

I have a table which has columns - `id(int)`, `date(DateTime)`, `value(float)`. I wanted to output daily average group by date of all rows which has `id=2.`

I wrote following sql query for that and query was working fine:

```
select cast(date as date), avg(value) from table where id=2 group by cast(date as date)
```

For the same problem, if I wanted to execute in sqlalchemy, I was using following expression :

```
>> from sqlalchemy import sql, types
>> x = sql.cast(Table.date, types.Date)
```

But when I tried executing x, I got following error :

```
>> x.execute()    
ArgumentError: Not an executable clause: CAST(Table.date AS DATETIME)
```

which means that SQL Server is considering that `types.Date as DateTime`. 
Please ignore the ArgumentError. What I am trying to focus on is that internal sql query is using `CAST(Table.date AS DATETIME)` rather than `CAST(Table.date AS DATE)`
Is there any way so that I can convert DateTime to Date in sqlalchemy?

Comment: You should use `sqlalchemy.func.cast` instead of `sqlalchemy.sql.cast`.

Comment: I tried using it. I got this error :- 

`ProgrammingError: (ProgrammingError) ('Invalid parameter type.  param-index=0 param-type=Date') 'SELECT cast(Table.date, ?) AS cast_1, avg(Table.value) AS avg_1 FROM Table AS Table_1 WHERE Table_1.id = ? GROUP BY cast(Table_1.date, ?)' [Date(), 2, Date()]`

Answer (score -1):

Following is wrong with you code:

1. you cannot execute a `clause`. You need to have a statement or a query (see below). This is the reason for the error that you get originally.
2. indeed, if you cast to `sa.Date`, `mssql` engine will cast to `DATETIME`. I am not entirely sure why this is, but i suspect it is because older versions of MSSQL did not have a separate `DATE`-only datatype. To solve this, simple cast it to the `DATE` datatype found in `mssql` dialect.

The code below should work. I do not have `mssql` right now, but I do show the compilation of the SQL statement for `mssql` instead:

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine, Column, Integer, Float, Date, DateTime, func
from sqlalchemy.dialects.mssql import DATE
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base

# @TODO: replace with your connection string
engine = create_engine('sqlite:///:memory:', echo=True)
Session = sessionmaker(bind=engine)
session = Session()

Base = declarative_base()


class MyTable(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'my_table'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    date = Column(DateTime())
    value = Column(Float())

Base.metadata.create_all(engine)

def get_mssql_sql(qry):
    from sqlalchemy.dialects import mssql
    dialect = mssql.dialect()
    return str(qry.compile(dialect=dialect))


# DATE = Date  # @note: this will not work in MSSQL (shows problem-2)
q = (session
     .query(func.cast(MyTable.date, DATE), func.avg(MyTable.value))
     .filter(MyTable.id == 2)
     .group_by(func.cast(MyTable.date, DATE))
     )
print(get_mssql_sql(q.statement))

# in your code, just run below to execute:
rows = q.all()
```